# Duplicate entry error on update using incoming Object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying a new way of updating Events (not Laravel Events, think like a party or cookout) for my server. My idea was to send an the Event with updated info into the controller through the request arguments. This updated event would have the same id as the Event it is an update of. An example is a birthday party event starting at 8:00 pm already saved in the database. I pass in an updated version of this event with the same id, but a start time of 9:00 pm. My goal is to avoid having to list all of the attributes of the party in the update controller. The issue I am having is that when I go to save the updated event, I hit a duplicate entry violation. The events have the same id, so I am a little confused as to why its not just performing an update. I'm assuming its something within the way Laravel handles object ids when its making DB updates. Any help or suggestions? Code is below.

Controller

```
public function update() {
        //Get updated event from request
        $event = request()->event;

        //Ensure current user created event
        if(Auth::user()->createdEvent($event)) {
            $event->save();
            return Constants::EVENT_UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        }

        return Constants::EVENT_FAILED_TO_UPDATE;
    }
```

Test

```
public function testUpdate() {
        //User for creating events
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        //Create base event and save to db
        $event = factory(Event::class)->create([
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

        //Matching event with all modified attributes
        $modifiedEvent = factory(Event::class)->make([
            'id' => $event->id,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

        $res = $this->call('POST', 'api/event/update', [
            'event' => $modifiedEvent,
            'api_token' => $user->api_token
        ]); 
    ............
}
```

Comment: why do you use factory to mock modified event? can't you just use `$event`? I think it has something to do with Laravel's internals. `make` tells the framework that the object is not yet saved in the database, so it will indeed try to save it to the database.

Comment: Because this is going to function as an API for a mobile app. I'm using because the incoming object won't be pulled from my server's database, it'll most likely be coming in as JSON.

Comment: yes, but in updating, do you really need to make a new object? is it not more correct to get the item to be updated from the database and then update it?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but my goal in writing it this way was to avoid having to write a line of code for each of the objects properties, setting time = newTime and location = newLocation. The only reason it will be a new object is because it's an object coming from the app.

Comment: what will happen if you do `'event' => $event` instead of `'event' => $modifiedEvent`?

Comment: It works fine using that, which I guess I expected. I just want to ensure there isn't a way to make it work similarly to the way I currently have it written.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying design in the Laravel framework prevents what I was trying to do above. The simplest approach ended up being the use of the functions getAttributes() and setRawAttributes(). https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getAttributes